# Phone looks different with Dart Flutter Emulator

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an application. On the emulator on the computer, it shows normally, as it should, but on the real phone it shows differently.

Emulator:

[image]

Real phone:

[image]

Why could this be? How can I solve it?

---

Codes:

```
Scaffold(
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Text("FAB"),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            body: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 40),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 15,),
                  Text("Profile", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 27),),
                  Divider(thickness: 1, color: Colors.black,),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text("Solved Tests:",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19)),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4,
                    child: Expanded(
                      child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: listUpload(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        late List<String?> items;
                        if (!snapshot.hasData){
                          return Text("Bulunamadı");
                        }
                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        items = [];
                        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                          snapshot.hasData) {
                        items = snapshot.data as List<String?>;
                        } else {
                          items = [];
                        }
                        return Scrollbar(
                          isAlwaysShown: true,
                          controller: _scrollContreller,
                          scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.right,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            controller: _scrollContreller,
                            itemCount: items.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, left: 10, right: 10),
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    
                                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  ),
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    title: Text(
                                      items[index].toString(),
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                    })),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 15,),
                  Center(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 250,
                          height: 40,
                          child: GFButton(
                            text: "Temizle", textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.red),
                            color: Colors.red,
                            type: GFButtonType.outline2x,
                            onPressed: () {
                              AlertDialog eminlik = AlertDialog(
                                title: Text("Onay"),
                                content: Text("Çözdüğünüz testlerin kayıtları silinecektir. Emin misiniz?"),
                                actions: [
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: Text("Evet"),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                      setState(() {
                                        eminlikSil();
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: Text("Hayır"),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },
                                  )
                                ],
                              );
                              showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => eminlik);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      ],
                    ),
                      
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              
            ),
            
          ),
```

I don't understand why this is so, but most likely there is a sizing issue. Thanks in advance for the help.

PS: I've tried it on several phones and it's like this on all phones.

---

When I run it I get a warning like this:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a ConstrainedBox widget.

The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  RichText ← Text ← FutureBuilder<dynamic> ← Expanded ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← Column ← Padding ← _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ← ⋯
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData.<anonymous closure>
#1      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData
#2      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject
#3      RenderObjectElement.mount
#4      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (30 frames)
#34     Element.inflateWidget
#35     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
#36     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (22 frames)
#58     Element.inflateWidget
#59     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
#60     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (117 frames)
#177    Element.inflateWidget
#178    Element.updateChild
#179    SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild
#180    SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure>
#181    BuildOwner.buildScope
#182    SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild
#183    RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure>
#184    RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure>
#185    PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees
#186    RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback
#187    RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild
#188    RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.insertAndLayoutChild
#189    RenderSliverFixedExtentBoxAdaptor.performLayout
#190    RenderObject.layout
#191    RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout
#192    _RenderSliverFractionalPadding.performLayout
#193    RenderObject.layout
#194    RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence
#195    RenderViewport._attemptLayout
#196    RenderViewport.performLayout
#197    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize
#198    PipelineOwner.flushLayout
#199    RendererBinding.drawFrame
#200    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
#201    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
#202    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
#203    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
#204    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
#208    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:150:10)
#209    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:270:5)
#210    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:114:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Doesn't you get any error about the `Expanded`? Because it should be a direct child of Column, Row or Flex I think.

Comment: @BélindaG.Freitas I added the error I got.

Comment: To be honest, it is really weird that the emulator shows fine, an expanded can't be inside a Container, it could be only inside Flexible widgets, so either a Column or a Row, you should swap the Container with the Expanded, or either depending on your expecting result you should ditch the container at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Expanded
```

Shouldn't be in Container. It've to be in Row/Column.